# JavaVM crashing when drawing using OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I've got the folowing code:

```
package test.opengl;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20.*;

public class GLClass extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    private int shaderProgram;
    private GL30 gl;

    FloatBuffer vertices;
    IntBuffer vao = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer vbo = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(1);

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        gl = Gdx.gl30;
        compileShaders();

        vertices = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(9);
        vertices.put(new float[]
                {
                        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
                });

        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, vbo);

        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao.get(0));
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo.get(0));
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao.get(0));
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(0);

        int err = gl.glGetError();
        if (err != 0)
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + err);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    private void compileShaders()
    {
        String vsSource;
        String fsSource;

        try
        {
            vsSource = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("shaders/shader.vert")));
            fsSource = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("shaders/shader.frag")));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        shaderProgram = gl.glCreateProgram();

        int vertexShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vsSource);
        gl.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        System.err.println(gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
        gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);

        int fragmentShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fsSource);
        gl.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        System.err.println(gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        gl.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    }
}
```

The code for shader.vert:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

The code for shader.frag:

```
#version 330
out vec4 out_Color;
void main()
{
    out_Color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

It is running on desktop and the program crashes as soon as the first call of render() is completed, without a stacktrace and a segfault log. config.useGL30 is set to true.

Why is it crashing? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can we see the code that is calling render(), as well as the proceeding lines? I do not see any specific issues with the code you displayed so I think it might be elsewhere.

Comment: the code that calls render is inside the LibGdx library itself

Comment: My guess is that the problem is in the shader's code. Can you show your `shaders/shader.vert` and `shaders/shader.frag`?

Comment: added the codes for shaders.